# How to get visual studio 2013 source control to ignore the packages directory

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget

I am using nuget automatic restore (the newer version, not MSBuild-integrated restore). When I build my solution, all the dependencies get downloaded, however, visual studio always adds the packages directory to source control (I'm using TFS). I've tried updating the .tfignore file and adding a .nuget/NuGet.config with  `<add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />`. But nothing seems to work. How do I make visual studio and tfs ignore the packages directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to right-click on the solution and click "Enable NuGet Package Restore".

Then add the following to .tfignore:

```
\packages*
```

**EDIT:** I originally followed the [instructions here for auto restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore) but was unsuccessful. Then I enabled Nuget Package Restore as described above. This worked, but is a deprecated feature (as noted by @Daniel Mann). Finally, I followed the [instructions here for migrating to auto restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore) and now everything works correctly. I don't know if this is the right procedure, but it worked for me.

Comment: Using the Visual Studio-integrated "Enable NuGet Package Restore" (which adds `NuGet.targets` and nuget.exe in addition to nuget.config) is **deprecated**. Please do not use it -- see this for more info: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore

Comment: So is the best practice to NOT checkin nuget packages to TFS?